# Python Koan 131 raising exceptions

Tags: python, exception

I am learning Python by doing Python Koans these days, and I came up with the problem of raising exceptions in Python. Specifically, I am even confused with `try...except...` after going through the koan. I know there is a similar question toward Rudy Koan [Ruby Koan 151 raising exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834203/ruby-koan-151-raising-exceptions). But I am a Python newbie and know nothing about Ruby.

So here is the koan:

```
# You need to finish implementing triangle() in the file 'triangle.py'
from triangle import *

class AboutTriangleProject2(Koan):
    # The first assignment did not talk about how to handle errors.
    # Let's handle that part now.
    def test_illegal_triangles_throw_exceptions(self):
        # Calls triangle(0, 0, 0)
        self.assertRaises(TriangleError, triangle, 0, 0, 0)

        self.assertRaises(TriangleError, triangle, 3, 4, -5)
        self.assertRaises(TriangleError, triangle, 1, 1, 3)
        self.assertRaises(TriangleError, triangle, 2, 4, 2)
```

the following is triangle.py

```
def triangle(a, b, c):
    # DELETE 'PASS' AND WRITE THIS CODE

    if a == b and b == c and c == a:
        return 'equilateral'
    if a == b or b == c or a == c:
        return 'isosceles'
    else:
        return 'scalene'

# Error class used in part 2.  No need to change this code.
class TriangleError(StandardError):
    pass
```

I am supposed to finish `triangle()` function.

To my understanding, the `try...except...` functions like if certain criteria satisfied then do something, else through out an exception. Then in my situation, should I use `if ... then raise TriangleError` or `try... except ...`? What are the differences between them?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Please see the following answer:

```
def triangle(a, b, c):
    # DELETE 'PASS' AND WRITE THIS CODE
    if min([a,b,c])<=0:
        raise TriangleError
    x,y,z = sorted([a,b,c])
    if x+y<=z:
        raise TriangleError
    if a==b and b==c and c==a:
        return 'equilateral'
    if a==b or b==c or a==c:
        return 'isosceles'
    else:
        return 'scalene'
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use raise, which will cause an exception to be created and travel up the call stack until something handles the exception with a try/except block. For example, if you were using this triangle function in real code you would do something like

```
try:
    t = triangle(x, y, z)
    ...
except TriangleError:
    print 'Triangle', x, y, z, 'is no good!'
```

That way you'd be able to handle the error when a bad triangle was made and your program wouldn't crash.

Answer (score 1):

here is my code,it worked

```
def triangle(a, b, c):
# DELETE 'PASS' AND WRITE THIS CODE
if min([a,b,c])<=0:
    raise TriangleError,"no <0 numbers"

if sorted([a,b,c])[0]+sorted([a,b,c])[1]<=sorted([a,b,c])[2]:
    raise TriangleError,"sf"

set_a=set(([a,b,c]))
if len(set_a)==1:
    return 'equilateral'
elif len(set_a)==2:
    return 'isosceles'
elif len(set_a)==3:
    return 'scalene'

# Error class used in part 2.  No need to change this code.
class TriangleError(StandardError):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with something similar to nancy's answer, using set rather than comparing a,b and c manually, and it worked also.

```
def triangle(a, b, c):
    # DELETE 'PASS' AND WRITE THIS CODE
    ls = sorted([a,b,c])
    if min(ls)<=0 or ls[0]+ls[1]<=ls[2]: raise TriangleError, 'Triángulo mal formado.'
    l = len(list(set(ls)))
    if(l==1): return 'equilateral'
    if(l==2): return 'isosceles'
    if(l==3): return 'scalene'

# Error class used in part 2.  No need to change this code.
class TriangleError(StandardError):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

The better solution for the triangle.py file has been given below:

```
def triangle(a, b, c):
if a <= 0 or b <= 0 or c <= 0:
    raise TriangleError(AttributeError('Negative edge is not allowed'))
if a + b + c <= 2 * max(a, b, c):
    raise TriangleError(AttributeError('largest side should be smaller than sum of 2 other sides'))
if a == b == c:
    return 'equilateral'
elif a == b or b == c or c == a:
    return 'isosceles'
return 'scalene'
```

## Error class used in part 2.  No need to change this code.

```
class TriangleError(Exception):
    pass
```